# Trouble with sort array nodejs java bubble, mongodb

Tags: javascript, integral

My Dave array in mongo bubble doesn't seem to want to function properly. When declaring the array it doesn't want to split to an integral value. If anyone has any code for that, it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What is "Dave array" ?

Comment: We are learning about them in class, its not very well known but its pretty much a function that can be used to split an integral for database use.

Comment: Could you provide me a link @brentis56 ? Cause otherwise this is really cryptic .. this doesn't look like a question at all and I don't know how someone has even marked the answer as intelligible when it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: I actually cant find a link sorry, as i said my teachers talking about it and so ill ask him if i can get some documentation on it. However the answer below does seem to work once ive floored it. If i can get my teacher to provide some documentation ill add a comment here. Sorry about that, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems seems to be you may have not floored the value. Try this, and Im sure it will work.